# Azure devops: How to add a parameter to a step in a steplist

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a template which takes a steplist which will only be ran in a certain scenario.  In part of the template the stepList can be used as is, but in another part I need to add a condition so it doesn't run if not applicable.  What I have tried is (condition is more complicated actually but I've tried this too):

```
- ${{ each step in parameters.preDeleteSteps }}:
  - ${{ each pair in step }}:
      ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
  condition: succeeded()
```

But this fails with:

```
/steps/terraform.yml@templates (Line: 132, Col: 7): Expected a mapping
/steps/terraform.yml@templates (Line: 131, Col: 7): Expected at least one key-value pair in the mapping
/steps/terraform.yml@templates: Unexpected state while attempting to read the mapping end. State:

MappingState:
  IsStart: True
  Index: 0
  IsKey: False
  IsEnd: False

SequenceState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 2
  IsEnd: False

IfExpressionState:
  IsSequenceInsertion: True
  IsStart: False

MappingState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 0
  IsKey: True
  IsEnd: False

SequenceState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 6
  IsEnd: False

MappingState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 0
 [...]
```

I have tried various approaches like putting the condition in `[{}]`, putting a dash in front of it, putting it first after the each step but all seem to end in error.  Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: Removed the actual condition I'm using as it's not relevant.  I've tried with the condition above and that fails with the same error.

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: mySteplist
  type: stepList
  default:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: test1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          
          Write-Host "Hello World1"
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: test2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          
          Write-Host "Hello World2"
        

jobs:
- job:
  displayName: testjobname
  steps:
  - ${{ each step in parameters.mySteplist }}: # Each step
    - ${{ each pair in step }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
      condition: eq(1,2) # contional expression here
```

And this works on my side:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I thought I had tried every kind of indentation but now that I see it it's obvious.  I had my condition at the same indentation as the dash but obviously in YAML syntax it should be in more as it's part of the list introduced by the dash.  Thanks for your help!