# Injecting an input to a step provided in a stepList?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline template that takes a `stepList`:

```
parameters:
- name: applicationDeploySteps
  type: stepList
  default: []
```

And injects the `stepList` into the template:

```
- deployment: Deploy_App
  displayName: Deploy Application
  pool: ${{ variables.AgentPool }}
  environment: ${{ parameters.Stage }}
  variables:
  - name: ServiceConnection
    value: SomeServiceConnection
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:          
        steps:    
          - ${{ each step in parameters.applicationDeploySteps }}:
            - ${{ each pair in step }}:
                ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

However, I'd like to provide an `AzureCLI@2` step, with the `azureSubscription` parameter being sourced from a variable inaccessible to the `AzureCLI@2` step at the time of template compilation:

```
extends:
  template: main.yml
  parameters:
    applicationDeploySteps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)
          addSpnToEnvironment: true
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            echo "do azurey things here"
```

The problem is in `azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)`. Obviously, that variable can't resolve. So the solution I'm shooting for is to inject the `azureSubscription` value in the template. However, I can't find a way to effectively iterate over the values provided in the `input` block.

```
- ${{ each pair in step }}:
    ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

will let me interrogate the *type* of the step. Trying to take it further just gives me a null reference exception when trying to queue the pipeline:

```
- ${{ each pair in step }}:
    ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'inputs') }}:
      - ${{ each input in pair.value }}:
          ${{ if eq(input.key, 'azureSubscription') }}:        
            ${{ input.key }}: ${{ variables.ServiceConnection }}
          ${{ else }}:
            ${{ input.key }}: ${{ input.value }}           
    ${{ else }}: 
      ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

That attempt gives me: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` with no corresponding line number. I'm guessing it's failing to iterate over `pair.value`, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot it further or get an idea of what I can and cannot iterate over. The documentation does not include more comprehensive examples, just checking if, say, it's a `script` task and blocking execution.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392651/azure-devops-how-to-add-a-parameter-to-a-step-in-a-steplist) is *similar*, but not the scenario that I'm implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
- ${{ each step in parameters.applicationDeploySteps }}:
  - ${{ each pair in step }}:
      ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'inputs') }}:
        inputs: 
          ${{ each input in pair.value }}: 
            ${{ if eq(input.key, 'azureSubscription') }}:
              ${{ input.key }}: ${{ variables.ServiceConnection }}
            ${{ else }}:
              ${{ input.key }}: ${{ input.value }}
      ${{ else }}: 
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

[This document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/each-expression.md) was useful for pointing me in the right direction, but honestly it was mostly trial-and-error.